# Windows search alternative (to search inside Word documents)

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, search

I have a large collection of word files (about 100,000) which I use for work. Naturally, I need to search for files with specific content and these search tend to be rather complex, e.g. often need to search for exact phrases, specific word combinations, etc...

In theory, Windows Search is supposed to do all of this... but it does not. I am using Windows 8.1, the files are indexed and the search works... sometimes in a way which I fail to understand. Search for word combinations with boolean AND/OR is a hit and miss...sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Same applies for whole phrases search (using quotation marks). What angers me is that it's not like Windows search does not work - it works, but it follows some weird logic which I just don't get and very often I do not get the results that I need.

The question - are there sane alternatives? (generally, I find Google search algorithms way more intuitive then Microsoft, too bad Google Desktop search is defunct).

Oh, and while we are on the subject, Outlook search replacement would also be very welcome. Same problem here - sometimes Outlook search works, sometimes it doesn't and I simply do not get the weird logic behind it.

Maybe I need a document management system... but these I looked at are clearly an overkill for my needs. I just need a search...

Comment: I used Google Desktop which was already installed on my machine for the exact same purpose and it worked wonderfully. As you mentioned it in defunct, but have you tried searching to make sure you can't get it from a third party site somewhere still?

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your question, Yes there are Windows 8.1 search alternatives out there that can help you with your unique and specific search queries.

There is a search utility called Rummage that allows you to specify as many search terms as you like to produce an increasingly refined results list.

With Rummage you can combine free text searches with tag searching for your complex search combining natural search with your specific content searches..  These tags are available on the user interface for selection and are created using information like your existing folder strictures, contacts, file types and date stamps.

Admittedly the 'OR' operation is a feature not yet implemented.  And Outlook search is also a future feature but both are in development.

Rummage is free and has other document management capabilities that might suit your needs.

Contact us via the website or the application if you have any queries.  Get an advanced copy of the latest version here:  http://bit.ly/RumA2

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend Agent Ransack for your needs, it has powerful search capabilities and i use it on my system. It supports windows 8.1 and it is free for both personal and commercial use. Agent Ransack Supports Regular Expression based search and search results can be exported to clipboard, TXT  or CSV file. You can download the software from [here](http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite/download) and read more about other windows search tools from my blog over [here](http://www.articpost.com/best-five-windows-search-alternatives/).